# jQuery Mobile themes no longer working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-templates

I recently changed from 1.0 to 1.1 without making any changes to the theme itself and the theme I made in the themeroller is no longer working (colors not showing up anymore). Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

The url in question is http://mobile.albertoandco.com (1.1)

http://mobile.albertoandco.com/zeus.do;MTg= (1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [a post a week ago in the jQueryMobile blog](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/) there is an answer to a comment saying "ThemeRoller will be ready when we hit 1.1 final in about 2 weeks. There will be a tool to upgrade your 1.0 theme to 1.1 too.".

So maybe for next week...